# User Model Serializer required Validation Error

Tags: python, django, rest, frameworks

I want to create a registration app for my project. 
Here is my serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model # If used custom user model

UserModel = get_user_model()


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)


    def create(self, validated_data):


        user = UserModel.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name']
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])

        return user


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password','email','first_name','last_name')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

As you see, I use UserModel which is one of the default models of rest_framework. I want to make first_name field required for my registration serializer.

Waiting for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `required=True` attrubute for `first_name` field:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
```